# JQuery AJAX call calls URI multiple times, scales with call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an web page I am creating to display information from a database, the page displays 2 tables, one pending table and one history table. The history table is automatically set to the current day's date. So when someone wants to change the date range to see the history, they change the date using a calendar date picker set up in JavaScript.

In this same file, I have an AJAX call that posts the new date filters. The first time it is clicked while on the page, it makes one call, then the second it makes 2 calls, the third it makes 4 calls, and so on making 2^n calls where n is the click number before refreshing the page.

This also happens with the other AJAX call I have happen which is to update the pending table automatically every 6 seconds.

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azXgm.png) is what the network calls look like when running. The code for this call is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Enable date picker for id startDate
  $("#startDate").datepicker();

  //Enable date picker for id endDate
  $("#endDate").datepicker();

  //Set the datepickers to read only so only the calendar can be used to select a date
  $("#startDate").attr({
    readOnly: false,
    style: "background-color:#FFFFFF"
  });
  $("#endDate").attr({
    readOnly: false,
    style: "background-color:#FFFFFF"
  });

  // update function to update pending table
  var update = function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "pending",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        //Replace existing table with data returned from query
        $('#pendTable').html(data);
        move();
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
        window.location.href = "";
      }
    });
  };

  // automatically updates the pending table every 6 minutes
  setInterval(update, 360000);

  //On filter change, submit the filters and update the table div
  $('.filter').on('change', function() {
    var filterValue = $(this).val(),
      startDate = document.getElementById('startDate').value,
      endDate = document.getElementById('endDate').value;

    $.ajax({
      url: "postFilters",
      async: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: $('#filters').serialize(),
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        //Replace existing table with data returned from query
        $('#histTable').html(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
        window.location.href = "";
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Also on my console it shoes that the call is being made multiple times , I have log inside the controllers to notify me when they are called and they are the same number of times it shows up on the network logs of Chrome.

What is wrong with this? I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Include HTML code.

Comment: Are you accidentally including the same javascript code in the `html` you are retrieving from the ajax request? Look at the request response text, if you have that is why. As this will cause the browser to add a `setInterval` call each time you append the new html.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much

Comment: Please include a [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There are pieces of information, such as your HTML which are required in order for someone to respond with an accurate, helpful answer. Help us, to help you! :)